# How I can play only mp4 type video tag in HTML5

Tags: javascript, html

```
  <video id="video1" controls="controls">
  <source src="demo.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="demo.ogg" type="video/ogg">
  Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
  </video>
```

I have used video tag of html 5 but it won't support mp4 file if I run it using following code

```
 <video id="video1" controls="controls">
 <source src="demo.mp4" type="video/mp4">
 Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
 </video>
```

Is there any solution for playing mp4 video in video tag it is very important for me to play mp4 video in video tag. Please help me.

Comment: I notice you asked this question few minutes back in another thread. BTW which browser and version are you using?

Answer (score 1):

You get better help from below URL.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML5_video

http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/video/basics/

Also, you can go with FLOW PLAYER it support all current browser for MP4 type

http://flowplayer.org/docs/

Hope, These will help you...!!